# Stable ID's in fiori launchpad

Tags: sapui5, primary-key

I am using a FlexColumnLayout for my app.

In the mid column I need to access a controll of the begin column of the FlexColumnLayout. Here is the problem:

Since it is a different view I cannot use

```
this.getView().byId("myId")
```

My first solution was to use stable ID's, by giving the views (XML) IDs.
Like that I could use:

```
sap.ui.getCore().byId("application---viewId--myId")
```

At first it worked just fine, but now that I integrated my app into the fiori launchpad the first part of the stable ID (the part before "viewId") changed and when I transport into productive it will change again.

Is there a way to access the mid column controls without sap.ui.getCore().byId?
Or is there a way to load the first part dynamically so I don't need to change my IDs when tranporting?

Sadly I don't know how to reproduce a Launchpad for testing purposes, but for those who want to test their ideas about my problem, my FlexColumnLayout is build just like in the DemoApp: https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/entity/sap.f.FlexibleColumnLayout

Comment: What is your greater goal? Why do you need to access the control of the begin column from your mid column?

Comment: @Marc it updates specific controlls, i could reload everything easily by using navigation, then i wouldn't need to get the controll from the outside, but reloading everything takes quite a while, i want to avoid that

Comment: Well this is still very unspecific. There are probably many good solutions to your problem. But avoid `sap.ui.getCore().byId()` at all costs. Have you heard of the event bus in UI5?

Comment: i am not shure how the event bus whould help me, can you refer to an explanation of the event bus and it's functions?

Comment: Controller A subscribes to event "myNewEvent". Controller B fires event "myNewEvent" (can even contain extra data). Event handler for "myNewEvent" in Controller A gets triggered and does stuff. https://blogs.sap.com/2015/10/25/openui5-sapui5-communication-between-controllers-using-publish-and-subscribe-from-eventbus/

Comment: Thanks for showing me this. Since I always used the controllers extend methode to reuse code I was not aware of this posibility. It indeed does work for my problem. But since the .getParent().getParent() way is shorter and I lazy, I'll proberly won't use it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys i found a solution:

```
this.getView().getParent().getParent()
```

returns the FlexColumnLayout. This has a method called "getBeginColumnPages", which returns an array of the views representing the begin column. Now that i can access the view in which my control is found, i can access it with the sap.ui.core.mvc.View.byId() method.

Now I have

```
this.getView().getParent().getParent().getMidColumnPages()[0].byId("myId")
```

Since the doulbe .getParent() doesn't seem to be ideal, please post a better solution if you know one : D

Comment: Why don't you access/change your control via a model that is bound to your component?

Comment: Can you bind controlls to a model? I olny used models to exchange primitive values

Comment: nvm just tested it, works like charm,  because thanks this I can also get rid of all the controlls I set in the innit methods of multiple controllers, THANKS

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `createId()` function, this will return the complete ID of your control.

```
this.byId(this.createId("myid"));
```